# How to finish this diagram with some tiny rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I already have some tikz code which is a frame structure stand for wireless network hidden problem

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw (0,-1)--(12,-1);
\node at (0.5,-2) {\tiny RF};
\draw [fill=gray] (0,-1) rectangle (.25em,0.125/4);
\draw (0 1,-1.25)--(1,-1.25);
\node at (0.5,0.05) {\tiny A};
\draw (0,0)--(0,-2);
\node at (1.5,0.05) {\tiny B};
\draw (1,0)--(1,-2);
\node at (2.5,0.05) {\tiny C};
\draw (2,0)--(2,-2);
\node at (3.5,0.05) {\tiny D};
\draw (3,0)--(3,-2);
\node at (4.5,0.05) {\tiny E};
\draw (4,0)--(4,-2);
\node at (5.5,0.05) {\tiny F};
\draw (5,0)--(5,-2);
\node at (6.5,0.05) {\tiny G};
\draw (6,0)--(6,-2);
\node at (7.5,0.05) {\tiny H};
\draw (7,0)--(7,-2);
\node at (8.5,0.05) {\tiny I};
\draw (8,0)--(8,-2);
\node at (9.5,0.05) {\tiny J};
\draw (9,0)--(9,-2);
\node at (10.5,0.05) {\tiny K};
\draw (10,0)--(10,-2);
\node at (11.5,0.05) {\tiny L};
\draw (11,0)--(11,-2);
\draw (12,0)--(12,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

now I want to fill with some tiny rectangles like the first in my figure RF"A", and followed by RF B, C, D... etc are all the  same
I'll try \draw [fill=gray] (0,-1) rectangle (.25em,0.125/4); this code below and change the coordinates. but the result is not I want. Please help me! is that clear?

Comment: Your question seems rather unclear to me... What prevents you from going further? What have you tried so far? Have you tried adapting  `\draw [fill=gray] (0,-1) rectangle (.25,0.125/4)`?

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you want to get and, if possible, add a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be what you tried to achieve? When I run your case and added more rectangles into the code, it seems that the rectangle got confused with the coordinates. So this solution uses relative coordinate `\draw (A) rectangle ++(x,y)` and the problem seems gone. This solution also simplies your code into `foreach loop` coding.

Note: Thanks to @Ignasi's comment which improves the code greatly.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{array}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw (0,-1)--(12,-1);
\foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {A, B, ..., L}{
\node at (\xi.5,0.05) {\tiny \x};
\node at (\xi.5,-2) {\tiny RF};
\draw (\xi,0)--(\xi,-2);
\draw [fill=gray] (\xi,-1) rectangle  ++(.25em,1+1/32);
}
\draw (12,0)--(12,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can save one variable with `\foreach \i [count=\xi from 0] in {A, B, ..., L}`

Comment: @Ignasi -- Thanks for the comment. That was a giant leap improving the code. APPRECIATED and code changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified and cleaned up version to produce what i assume you try to achieve. It's partly taken from Jesse's [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197960/34759) and tries to simplify the code for a better understanding.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
 \draw (0,0) -- ++(12,0);
 \foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {A,...,L} {
  \draw [fill=gray] (\x, -1) -- ++(0,1) rectangle ++(.1,1);
  \node at (\x.5, 1) {{\tiny \l}};
  \node at (\x.5,-1) {{\tiny RF}};
 }
 \draw (12,-1) -- ++(0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The height of the rectangles can be adjusted by modifying the `y` value of the rectangle's second (relative) coordinate.